# Understanding Cross Entropy Loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I see a lot of explanations about CEL or binary cross entropy loss in the context where the ground truth is say, a 0 or 1, and then you get a function like:

```
def CrossEntropy(yHat, y):
    if yHat == 1:
      return -log(y)
    else:
      return -log(1 - y)
```

However, I'm confused at how BCE works when your yHat is not a discrete 0 or 1. For example if I want to look at reconstruction loss for an MNIST digit where my ground truths are 0 < yHat < 1, and my predictions are also in the same range, how does this change my function?

EDIT:

Apologies let me give some more context for my confusion. In the PyTorch tutorials on VAEs they use BCE to calculate reconstruction loss, where yhat (as far as I understand, is not discrete). See:

https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py

The implementation works...but I don't understand how that BCE loss is calculated in this case.

Comment: For autoencoders with images you can normalize your pixel values to range `[0, 1]` and then use BCE pixel-wise

Comment: Sure, but is that what they're doing here?

Comment: In the code that you posted, the code handles more than just 0 and 1. The first `if` statement handles the case of  `1`, but the `else` statement handles all other values, not just `0`.

Comment: Check out http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits and http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss they take the sigmoid function from the data, so it gets normalized into `[0, 1]`

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 - right, but this code would not work properly (as in calculate the proper CE loss) if it took anything that wasn't 0 or 1.

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990250/what-is-cross-entropy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross entropy measures distance between *any* two probability distributions. In what you describe (the VAE), MNIST image pixels are interpreted as probabilities for pixels being "on/off". In that case your target probability distribution is simply not a dirac distribution (0 or 1) but can have different values. See [the cross entropy definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy).

With the above as a reference, let's say your model outputs a reconstruction for a certain pixel of 0.7. This essentially says that your model estimates p(pixel=1) = 0.7, and accordingly p(pixel=0) = 0.3.
 If the target pixels would just be 0 or 1, your cross entropy for this pixel would either be -log(0.3) if the true pixel is 0 or -log(0.7) (a *smaller* value) if the true pixel is 1.
The full formula would be -(0*log(0.3) + 1*log(0.7)) if the true pixel is 1 or -(1*log(0.3) + 1*log(0.7)) otherwise.

Let's say your target pixel is actually 0.6! This essentially says that the pixel has a probability of 0.6 to be on and 0.4 to be off.
This simply changes the cross entropy computation to -(0.4*log(0.3) + 0.6*log(0.7)).

Finally, you can simply average/sum these per-pixel cross-entropies over the image.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-entropy loss is only used in classification problems: i.e., where your target (`yHat`) is discrete. If you have a regression problem instead, something like the mean squared error (MSE) loss would be more appropriate. You can find a variety of losses for the PyTorch library, and their implementations [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/loss.html).

In the case of the MNIST dataset, you actually have a multiclass classification problem (you're trying to predict the correct digit out of 10 possible digits), so the binary cross-entropy loss isn't suitable, and you should the general cross-entropy loss instead.

Regardless, the first step in your investigation should be identifying whether your problem is "classification" or "regression". A loss function suitable for one problem is generally not suitable for the other.

EDIT: You can find a more detailed explanation of the cross-entropy loss in the context of the MNIST problem at the ["MNIST for ML Beginners" tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/mnist/beginners) on the TensorFlow website.

Comment: Hmm im mainly confused in the context of VAEs. For example, in the pytorch official example, BCE is used for reconstruction loss: https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/vae/main.py

Comment: The adversarial problem is different from the traditional MNIST classification problem. In the adversarial problem, the second net tries to output a probability that the image generated by the first net is of real data. This is a binary problem: real vs. fake. In the traditional classification problem, the (single) net tries to output the probabilities that the image corresponds to any of the digits. This is a multiclass problem: 0 vs 1 vs 2 vs etc.

Comment: Anyway, for the real vs. fake problem, BCE is appropriate. The function you've written should work as normal, except `yHat` is 0 if the image is fake and 1 if it is real; `y` is the probability of it being real (generated by the second net).

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I'm referring to a variational autoencoder, not a GAN.

Comment: Also, I would love to see the source but I had a bit of trouble digging for it. If I remember correctly the nn modules call the F. modules, which in turn for BCE calls something else (a file in C?), and I had trouble actually digging it up...

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't encode set of classes that isn't binary as values between 0 and 1.  In the case of MNIST, if you were to label each digit 0, 0.1, 0.2, etc, this implies that an image of a 2 is more similar to an image of a 0 than an image of a 5, which isn't necessarily true.

One good thing to do is to "one hot encode" your labels instead, as a 10 element array of 0s. Then, set the index corresponding to the digit image to 1.

As mentioned above, you would then use the regular cross-entropy loss function.  Your model should then output a vector of conditional probabilities for each sample, corresponding to each possible class.  Probably using a softmax function.