# Formula for Cross-Entropy Loss for Vector Inputs

Tags: loss-function, cross-entropy

I'm using cross-entropy loss for a multi-class classification task with vector inputs for both true class distribution `y_i` and softmax predictions `p_i`.
I'm a bit confused about the notation when dealing with vector inputs for both the true class distributionand the softmax predictions. Is the notation

$\ell_{CE}(y_i, p_i) = -\sum_{i=1}^k y_i \log p_i$

[image]

correct for handling these vectors, or should additional subscripts $j$ as well like this?

$\ell_{CE}(y_i, p_i) = -\sum_{j=1}^{k} y_{ij} \log p_{ij}$

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain how this is a programming question.

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular
 I saw several non-programming question here at cross-entropy related to loss. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990250/what-is-cross-entropy. I'm hoping to learn about my question from someone who knows both math and programming.  Thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't help your case to link to a question that was closed as off-topic several years ago. It does, however, suggest that [datascience.se] may be appropriate. Check that your question in on-topic there by consulting their help centre before you post.